# Enable/Disable an asp:TextBox Control based on CheckBox.Checked true or false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I need to enable/disable an asp.TextBox/Input depending on a CheckBox. If the CheckBox.Checked = true then I need to enable the asp.TextBox/Input or if the CheckBox.Checked = false I then need need to disable the asp.TextBox/Input.

Below is the code I have but it only works on first click, meaning if I check the box it will enable the asp.TextBox/Input but if I uncheck it will not disable the asp.TextBox/Input.

Also, by default the asp.TextBox/Input is disable on Page_Load.

```
//If checked it should enable the input.
//If unchecked it should disable the input.
If Port is Required?<label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="isportreqinput" name="isportreqinput" runat="server" onclick="fncport(this.form.isportreqinput, this.form.porttxt);"  />
                        <span class="metro-checkbox">Check Me</span>
                    </label>

//This is the input I need to disable/enable depending on the checkbox
<input type="text" name="porttxt" id="porttxt" runat="server" disabled="disabled" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fncport(control, objname) {

            if (control.checked == true) {
                objname.disabled = false;
            }
            if (control.cheched == false) {
                objname.disabled = true
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Hmmm... strange. Why does it anything at all? `fncport(this.form.isportreqinput, ...)` should not know the control because per default ASP.net renders another ID.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean?

Comment: If you look at the rendered HTML code in your browser, the IDs of your controls should be something not really beautiful like `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_isportreqinput`. But your `onclick` handler calls the function with the original IDs. If you didn't change the default ID rendering, this should be `fncport(this.form.<%=isportreqinput.ClientID%>, ...)` to get the rendered client id.

Comment: I should point out a business logic issue.  If the input should be disabled when the checkbox is checked, why is the input disabled when the page loads, but the checkbox is unchecked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.form.isportreqinput` is not a valid way to get a reference to the isportreqinput checkbox from within your HTML.  `this` is actually a reference to the checkbox.

If you need to pass in the ids of the checkbox and input to your function, pass them in as text and use `document.getElementById()`

```
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="isportreqinput" name="isportreqinput" runat="server"    
        onclick="fncport('isportreqinput', 'porttxt');"  />
    <span class="metro-checkbox">Check Me</span>
</label>

<input type="text" name="porttxt" id="porttxt" runat="server" disabled="disabled" />
```

Also, you mispelled `checked` in the second if statement.  You don't even need either if statement, just set the disabled value to the opposite of the checked value.

```
    function fncport(controlid, objnameid) {
        var control = document.getElementById(controlid);
        var objname = document.getElementById(objnameid);

        objname.disabled = !control.checked;
    }
```

Comment: Also because the controls runs with runat="server" the ids changes, and you probably need to call them with the ClientID

Comment: @Aristos, Yes, sorry, missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you pasted your code or copied it. But there are a few syntax issues:

```
 if (control.cheched == false) {
            objname.disabled = true
 }
```

Should be:

```
 if (control.checked == false) {
            objname.disabled = true;
 }
```